# C++20 doesn't support semantic import in .mm files

Tags: c++, xcode, c++20

I've set the C++ language dialect in my xcode project to c++2a.

Than it failed on compiling .mm file which has the following line

```
@import AppKit;
```

Which has passed compilation when the compiler was set to c++17 or below.

If replace it with the following line and link with framework from project build phases, than it works.

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

My `.mm` file is include for adapter swift header file (*-Swift.h) which is auto generated and has this @import directive so I cannot avoid it using the workaround from above.

Does anybody have encountered such issue ? any thoughts how to resolve it ?

UPDATE:

Xcode 13 is about to be released with built-in support in c++20 standard, Perhaps someone had the chance to check this version and see if the problem is resolved ?

> Apple Clang Compiler
> New Features in Xcode 13 Beta 3
> You can now configure the C++20 and GNU++20 C++ language dialects
> in Xcode’s build settings.

Comment: Yes, I have encountered this issue. I have reported it to Apple. I am glad that I am not the only one to have tried Objective-C++ in C++20 mode with Swift bridge...

Comment: @prapin, so we're on the same boat here... can you suggest a workaround for this issue ? I cannot avoid the auto-generated swift adaptor header, but maybe there's a way to make it replace the `@import` with `#import` and add the framework manually to the project ?

Comment: Well, for the moment, I just didn't switch to C++20 yet (mostly because of that bug).  If my case, I could live by including a modified copy of the auto-generated header, since we have a single class in Swift that we don't touch. But we plan to use more Swift in the future, so definitely not a viable workaround in the long term.

Comment: I checked Xcode 13 Beta 2, the problem was still there. It did not have C++20 selectable. I will try Xcode 13 Beta 3.

Comment: Well, the bug is still present in Xcode 13 beta 3 :(

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been fixed by Apple.

Please download Xcode 13 Beta 5 or newer.
That should solve the issue.